# MapKit : null visibleMapRect values despite correct display

Tags: ios, core-data, mapkit, master-detail

I am playing with the Map Kit and perform this after navigating to a specific MKMapRect:

```
    double x=_detailViewController.mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x;
    double y=_detailViewController.mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.y;
    double w=_detailViewController.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width;
    double h=_detailViewController.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.height;
    NSLog(@"Saving %@ as (%f,%f)(%f,%f)",placeName,x,y,w,h);
```

The problem is that I get this:

```
2014-08-03 17:03:46.452 Places[13194:60b] Saving 'there' as (0.000000,0.000000)(0.000000,0.000000)
```

Even though my Map View shows the location properly.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

In invoke the `saveLocation`method in the MasterViewController which handles all the Coredata stuff.

It looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)addLocation
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    postNotificationName:@"addLocation"
    object:self];
}
```

Here's a few MVC bits:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(addLocationNotificationReceived:)
                                                 name:@"addLocation"
                                               object:_detailViewController];
```

...and, as suggested by Anna, `detailViewController`is nil.

```
    double x=_detailViewController.mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x;
    double y=_detailViewController.mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.y;
    double w=_detailViewController.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width;
    double h=_detailViewController.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.height;
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:x] forKey:@"mapX"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:y] forKey:@"mapY"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:w] forKey:@"MapW"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:h] forKey:@"MapH"];
    NSLog(@"Saving %@ as (%f,%f)(%f,%f)",placeName.text,x,y,w,h);
```

**Why?** I just navigated its `mapView`object?

Comment: Also log the value of _detailViewController and _detailViewController.mapView (they may be nil).  Where exactly is this called?  Before the pushViewController/presentViewController?  Show some more of the surrounding code.

Comment: Hello Anna, thanks for your reply, indeed, the mapView doesn't seem to be set though I just used it!?

Comment: If this code is called before the push, the mapView may not have been initialized yet when this code runs (perhaps before the detailVC's viewDidLoad has executed).  Need answers to the other questions and some more context of where/when this code is running.  Also, why not log the map view's visibleMapRect in _detailViewController itself in a method such as viewDidAppear or regionDidChangeAnimated?  Why is this code directly accessing views inside another view controller?

Comment: This is called after the push as I invoke the addLocation method from the detailViewController. The save method is in the MasterViewController to keep the Coredata at the same place.

Comment: Just added some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed this by saving my MapView's details in an NSDictionary which I send as userInfo with my NSNotification.

I still don't understand why a visible UI Object was not nil once back in the MVC but I guess it might have been unloaded at that very moment.

Many thanks to Anna for her help.